# xIs initializing objects using a filepath string as the argument bad coding practice?

Tags: java

I am a first-year computer science student trying to tackle a big application.
I wish to work on developing a living card game known as A Game Of Thrones Second Edition, in the hope that along the way I will learn more about Java and best programming practices.

One thing I've struggled with is initializing cards. I currently have a class Deck that contains an ArrayList of cards and upon initializing Deck as an object, it takes a file path as an argument e.g.

```
    Deck deck = new Deck("C:/users/.../deck1.txt");
```

This will then transform the card information within deck1.txt into Card Objects, which are then stored into the Card ArrayList within the Deck Object.

The Card class works in a similar fashion, taking a file path String as an argument e.g.

```
    Card card1 = new Card("C:/users/.../Robb Stark(Core Set).txt");
```

in order to load the required information for the unique card.

Is this a stupid way to initialize Card Objects? Or any object for that matter? I am uncertain of how I would otherwise do this.

Comment: From a performance point of view, I see nothing wrong with this, though you might want to use variables, possibly constants, as parameters to the constructors, rather than hard-coding values.

Comment: consider using a properties file to store the filename/path

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, do you mean having variables such as Card Cost, Card Strength ect become the parameters to the Card constructor? If so, how could I load the variable data from a file? I plan to have a folder full of all the characters that contains information about these variables. I already have a few, and that is how Iv been assigning these variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) (SRP) is a guideline stating that a class should generally focus on doing one thing, and recommends splitting up responsibilities between classes/modules. The Deck/Card constructors should probably not have the responsibility of reading a file from the file system and parsing it from there.

It would probably be better to get the information out of the file somewhere else and then pass that into the Deck/Card constructor. This is where I would personally probably use a [Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) to construct the object. You could pass a File object to a factory method that knows how to construct the Card/Deck from there:

```
class DeckFactory {

    public static Deck createDeckFromFile(File deckFile) {
        String fileString = readFileToString(deckFile); // not-shown helper method

        // depending on how information is stored in string, get fields from string, i.e.:
        String[] fields = fileString.split(":"); // if fields were delimited by :
        String deckName = fields[0]; 
        // and other etc. fields...

        // then construct your deck
        return new Deck(deckName, deckSize, deckType); // and other properties...
    }
}
```

This could be called from your other code like:

```
String deckFilepath = "C:\Users\...\decks\deck1.txt";
Deck myDeck = DeckFactory.createDeckFromFile(new File(deckFilePath));
```

The DeckFactory could also have another method for creating a Deck by just passing in the strings themselves, or maybe from a different type of object, or really anything. The Factory has the responsibility of knowing how to create the object. The same thing can be done for Card with a CardFactory.

Additionally, as other comments/answers have mentioned it may be best to read the filepath strings for the cards/decks from a properties/configuration file. This would prevent hardcoding the string in the code itself.

Comment: Does this use the Factory Design Method? It sounds very similar, and I was thinking of using it as I believe Ill end up giving Card a few subclasses for Character, Location, Event, Attatchment and Plot - all of which have different attributes and roles but are all considered cards. Would you be able to provide a link to some solid information regarding properties and configuration files? I have honestly never heard of them until now. Thanks for any additional information, I am going to mark this as the answer for addressing the main question.

Comment: Sure thing, a little googling came up with: Oracle documentation on properties - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html and a practical explanation from Mkyong  https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Comment: And to the "Factory Design Method" question, that is technically a different pattern - the one I mentioned is really just the "Factory" pattern. But you could use the "Factory Method" pattern too - in the example above, if we had used a CardFactory, instead of calling return new Card(args) at the end, you would call a static method like return Card.createCard(args) instead. However, createCard would return a subclass of Card (like CharacterCard, LocationCard, etc.) instead of a Card itself, based on the arguments given. See https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method for examples.

Comment: I didn't even know there was a difference between the two! Thanks for pointing that out. Is it smart to incorporate both Factory and Factory design patterns? I'm yet to try it, but in my mind that would work. Not sure if that is recommended though. I am currently presuming Factory Design is better when initializing subclass objects that share the same superclass and Factory is better when not dealing with subclasses. I will  look into it further.

Comment: Both have their uses - I believe a Factory can still be useful in your case to handle the File-related logic. And yes, the Factory Method pattern is handy for getting subclass objects - but one tip I would add is to not get too stuck on one pattern or another. You may get to coding the meat and potatoes of your app and realizing that this or that pattern is overkill. So keeping an open mind and not forcing the use of certain patterns is also important.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your cards are fixed, you can bundled the cards with your application. Say in a resources folder.
Then create a properties file that points to this directory and load all cards.
Or in the properties files you have listed out all cards.

The Decks seem to be user specific, so they can be at a specific location in user home or something that the user can point to.

Comment: Would this be more efficient than trying to load data from txt files? I have essentially written my txt files that represent cards in a specific way e.g.

Name: Robb Stark.
Cost: 6.

I use .split() to assign the values to the desired variable within the Card class.

Comment: Even in this method,the card files stay. What I wanted to bring out was that cards are probably something that you as a game designer have created, so you can bundle them with the app. They are still files, the path to the files or the list of files can be in a properties/config file

Comment: I think I will in fact end up doing just that. Thanks for the advice!